# XML - Namespaces

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Considering the following XML document:

```
1 <a
2     x:foo="123" xmlns:x="foo">
3  <b xmlns="bar"
4      y="456">
5   <c xmlns:x="baz">
6    <x:d xmlns="">
7     <e xmlns:y="asdf"/>
8    </x:d>
9   </c>
10  <f xmlns:x="bar"/>
11 </b>
12 </a>
```

For lines 1–7 and 10, which namespace URI does the element or attribute declared on that line have? Some kind of explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick summary.

- When you use `xmlns` without declaring a prefix, the namespace it declares be inherited by all *elements* in that scope (the element where you declared it and all the unprefixed elements it contains, until another `xmlns` with a different value is declared).
- Attributes don't inherit namespaces. They must be qualified with a prefix.
- When you use `xmlns:prefix`, the namespace it declares be inherited by all prefixed *elements* in that scope (the prefixed element where you declared it and all the prefixed elements it contains, until another `xmlns:prefix` with a different value is declared). If the element where it is declared does not have the same prefix, or no prefix, it will not be part of the namespace.

Based on that, in your example:

- `a` and `e` belong to no namespace. `a` because it has no `xmlns` declaration and no parents. `e` because its parent has a `xmlns=''` attribute which makes the default namespace null.
- `b`, `c` and `f` belong to the `bar` namespace. `b` because it declares the default namespace as `xmlns='bar'` and has no prefix. `c` and `f` because they have no prefix and inherit the default namespace from their parent.
- `d` belongs to the `baz` namespace because of the `x` prefix which explicitly qualifies it, but its unqualified contents (`e`) now belong to no namespace because of `xmlns=''`.
- `e` declares the `asdf` namespace and assigns it to the `y` prefix but no element or attribute uses it.
- `f` redeclares the `x` atrribute with a different namespace `bar` which would be applied to any prefixed child of `f` if there were any (or to `f` if it were prefixed by `x`).
- The `foo` attribute in `a` belongs to the `foo` namespace, because it is qualified by the `x` prefix.
- The `y` attribute in `b` belongs to no namespace, because it has no prefix.

See the other answer by @MichaelKay which links to a very good tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

James Clark's explanation of namespaces

http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

remains as good as any. If you still have questions after reading that, then tell us which parts you don't understand.